# railstutorial how to add debug to test

Tags: railstutorial.org

I understand how to add

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

but why will

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.test? %>
```

not do any good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActionView::Helpers::DebugHelper#debug`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html) "returns a YAML representation of object wrapped with `<pre>` and `</pre>`", and putting it between `<%= %>` on a page displays it, so it can help when debugging through the browser as you always have a page open.

In a testing environment though, you're mostly running 'headless' (not using a browser), so you've got nothing to display since you don't have a page open.

If you want to debug your tests during runtime (do stuff like see what values are being assigned to your variables during your tests etc), then you can absolutely do that with gems like [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).